# Either $\det(AB) = 0$ or $\det(BA) = 0$ when $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Here is an observation I made:

> If A and B are two non square matrices conformable for multiplication then either $\det(AB) =0$ or $\det(BA)=0$ or both.

I could come up with this proof:

> Let  $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n \times m}$. WLOG, let $m < n$. Then $\text{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B)) \leq \min(m,n) = m$. Simillarly, $\text{rank}(BA) \leq \min(\text{rank}(A), \text{rank}(B)) \leq \min(m,n) = m$. But order of $AB=m$ and order of $BA = n$. Hence matrix $BA$ has rank less than its order.

Is this proof(and consequently the theorem) correct? And are there any alternative proofs?

Comment: There are a lot of proofs possible using the invertible matrix theorem.

Comment: another proof: suppose WLOG that $m\lt n$: then the $n\times n$ matrix  $\left[\begin{matrix}AB &\mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0\\ \end{matrix}\right]$  and $(BA)$ have the same characteristic polynomial.  The former must have determinant $0$ so the latter does as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Basically if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times m$, $m<n$ then $A$ can be seen a a linear function from $n$ dimensions into $m$ dimensions and $B$ can be seen as a function of $m$ dimensions into $n$ dimensions.

Thus the image of $B$ is a space of degree $n$ and of dimension at most $n$. Thus the $A(\mathrm {Im} B)$ is a space of degree $m$ but dimension at most $n$.